# Make array same length as other array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1 => '12', 2 => '4', 3 => '54');
$array2 = array(1 => '12', 2 => '4', 3 => '54', 4 => '124');
```

How would I go about making `$array2` have the same number of keys as `$array1`, and removing any at the end.

So, I would end up with:

```
$array2 = array(1 => '12', 2 => '4', 3 => '54');
```

Being aware that the first array may contain a different number of keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$array2 = array_slice($array2, 0, count($array1), true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use array_slice, but I couldn't get it to work (I had the count as the second option, and no 0). Thanks! (I'll accept in 9 minutes).

Answer (score -1):

you can also yuse array_pop it removes the last element from the array

[array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: That isn't of any use to me - I made need to remove more than one entry.

Comment: It's not as _elegant_ but you can do it in a while:


```while( count( $array1) < count $array2 ) { array_pop( $array1); }```